# Plot a vector against a generated date sequence

Tags: r, date, seq

Suppose I have a vector of numbers from 1:12 and want to plot them over period of time ranged from Jan. 2013 to Dec. 2013. I used the following code to generate the data and plotting:

```
dates<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12) 
n<-seq(1:12)
df<-cbind(dates,n)
plot(df)
```

However, some problems come up with the last code; Firstly could not find an option in the first `seq` to generate only months and year without day. Secondly, all dates in `df` become serial even after adding `as.Date` before `dates` in `cbind`. Finally, the x axis in the plot not in the time format as a result of the last two problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-data.frame(dates=dates,n=n)
plot(df$dates, df$n, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, labels=format(df$dates, "%b %Y"), at=df$dates)
axis(2)
```

Comment: Works fine. Would appreciate if you tell how can I add years to the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
plot(dates,n)
```

without cbinding it. cbind creates a matrix (see `class(df)`). Within this process the dates are saved as class numeric.

[image]

For nicer and easier to customize plots use

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(dates,n) + xlab("") + ylab("my y lab")
```

[image]